# how to use utl_file in type declaration

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am creating a type and I would like to use utl_file package inside it. Unfortunatly I have a message :

```
MEMBER FUNCTION draw(fichier utl_file.file_type) RETURN NUMBER,

PLS-00201:identifier utl_file.file_type must be declared
```

Some might say that I need to grant execute on utl_file package to the user but this is not the solution here because the user already has the privilege as I can use utl_file inside my packages

Thank you for your answers

Comment: I can confirm that the situation exists, and appears to be a matter of being unable to pass any RECORD type to a member procedure of an object type.  This is probably documented somewhere but I haven't found it yet.  There *is* [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/10_objs.htm) which states (under "Components of an Object Type") that type **attributes** cannot be RECORD types (among others).  I'm guessing this applies to parameters to member procs as well.  Share and enjoy.

Comment: I have the answer... thank you ... no type define in packages which seems to be the case here with utl_file... so it is not possible.. too bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/10_objs.htm) for PL/SQL Object Types.  Under "Methods" it states, "The datatype (of a parameter) can be any Oracle type except those disallowed for attributes".  Among the other things which are thus disallowed are types defined in a PL/SQL package such as UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

--declare the utility file type

```
V_FILE_ID_OUT := UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
```

-- store file opening option in the utility

```
V_FILE_ID_OUT :=
         UTL_FILE.FOPEN ('/path/',
                         filename,
                         'W'
                        );
```

--write into the file your message

```
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE (V_FILE_ID_OUT, 'message');
```

--close the utility option

```
UTL_FILE.FCLOSE (V_FILE_ID_OUT);
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure it is PLSQL? That's not the sintax to create functions. Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION draw (fichier utl_file.file_type) RETURN NUMBER
IS
    A NUMBER;
    --declare your variables
BEGIN
    A:=1;
    --code your process
RETURN A; --your return value
END;
/
```

Comment: OP is creating an **object type** and is trying to declare a member procedure which accepts a UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE record as a parameter.